Sending volume_up_key_code 115 from Raspberry Pi 5 to iPhone
The shutter of iPhone cameras can be remotely released with volume_up_key_code 115. For example, the small remote shutters send bluetooth command volume_up_key_code 115 to release the camera shutter. My goal is to remote control the shutter of iPhone camera from a Python3 code running in a Raspberry Pi 5.
The Bluetooth part, however, seems to be tricky. Although I have a Bluetooth connection between the Raspberry Pi and the iPhone, and furthermore, although bluetoothctl and thereafter devices commands show me the connection is established, I have not managed to create a python code that recognised the connection.
I've installed Bluez and Bleak --installing PyBluez to Raspberry Pi5 does not seem to work–- and have tried to create python code with bleak but, for example, the following code already fails in connecting to the iPhone. Is anybody able to help and suggest what is the issue?
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

# Replace with your mobile phone's Bluetooth address
DEVICE_ADDRESS = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" # here I set the actual iPhone DEVICE_ADDRESS

# UUID for the characteristic that accepts keyboard input
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00002a4d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

# Key code for "volume up"
VOLUME_UP_KEY_CODE = 115

async def send_volume_up_command(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        if client.is_connected:
            print(f"Connected to {address}")
            # Send the volume up key code
            await client.write_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, bytearray([VOLUME_UP_KEY_CODE]))
            print("Volume up command sent")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to connect to {address}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(send_volume_up_command(DEVICE_ADDRESS))


Can you elaborate on what error you are getting when connecting (constructing the BleakClient)? Does it have an error-code?

Thank you for you feedback. No error code, here's shortened version of the beginning and end of the output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Desktop/py_code/volume_up_key_code.py", line 24, in 
loop.run_until_complete(send_volume_up_command(DEVICE_ADDRESS))
...
File "/home/user/Desktop/py_code/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 145, in connect
raise BleakDeviceNotFoundError(
bleak.exc.BleakDeviceNotFoundError: Device with address A0:4F:8A:D4:D5:2F was not found.

You might try sending Volume Up as code 123 as this is what is described as working here from the "AB Shutter 3" device (which I've used in the past and can affirm it's worked.)
https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/02/cheap-bluetooth-buttons-and-linux/
"It turns out that the iOS buttons sends Volume Up (key 123) whereas the Android button sends Enter (key 36)."
Please let us know if that fixed anything!
Also...
The second answer in this post:
Remote bluetooth camera trigger for phone
Links to github code demo'ing communication with RPi controlling iPhone shutter (volume up.)

There is a project here that did it with a Raspberry Pi:
https://gist.github.com/ukBaz/a47e71e7b87fbc851b27cde7d1c0fcf0#gistcomment-2997623
This was an experiment to turn a Raspberry Pi into a Human Interface Device (HID). A keyboard to be more precise.

